# mysql update dos tablas sin id

Tags: sql

Buen día. Tengo una tabla (A) con varios campos y otra tabla (B) con cuatro campos con los cuales quiero actualizar en la primer tabla. Un problema es que la segunda tabla (B) no coincide en el número de registros (500 registros) que tiene la primer tabla (A)(6000 registros) por lo que no hay un ID en común lo que dificulta la tarea. Estoy tomando una columna presente en ambas tablas para tomarlo como identificador. Ya tengo una función para hacer el update pero sólo funciona parcialmente, pues inserta el primer valor de la segunda tabla (B) en los seis mil registros de la primera tabla (A).

Puede hacerse el update en consola o tengo que hacerlo manualmente uno por uno??

```
UPDATE A_posts, B_posts
SET B_posts.post_director = A_posts.post_director
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT DISTINCT t1.post_title
FROM B_posts as t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT post_title FROM A_posts as t2 WHERE t2.post_title = t1.post_title))
```

La columna que estoy tomando como identificador en común es post_title, es decir, si post_title coincide en ambas tablas entonces hace el update de post_director

Aunque funciona parcialmente no se si está bien planteada la consulta porque obviamente no hace lo que quiero.

Comment: Entiendo que solo quieres actualizar la tabla B. Que valor debe adquirir B_posts.post_director si no existe una coincidencia en post_title?

Comment: La tabla A tiene ID, post_a, post_b, post_title, post_director, (13 columnas en total). La tabla B solo tiene cuatro columnas post_a, post_b, post_title, post_director (cuatro columnas), obviamente la tabla A es la que usa la web, pero necesito actualizarla con los datos de la tabla B

Answer (score 1):

La sentencia para actualizar la tabla A seria esta:

```
UPDATE 
    A_Post
JOIN
    B_Post B
    ON B.post_title = A.post_title
SET
    A.post_director = B.post_director;
```

Solo se actulizaran los registros de la tabla A donde `post_title` coincida en las dos tablas.

Comment: Interesante propuesta. La pruebo y comento. Gracias!!